# how to custom style the number format in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Suppose I say I have number eg:89000000000 I need to format like 89,00,00,000.00 in this format of Indian numerical system as crores.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula should work:

```
CStr({TableName.NumberColumnName}, "##,##,##,##,###.##"))
```

To explicitly specify the digit grouping character, add those parameters:

```
CStr({TableName.NumberColumnName}, "##,##,##,##,###.##", 2, ",")
```

(The digit grouping character depends on the system settings if not specified explicitly.)